# Frage über den Satzbau eines Satzteiles

Tags: sentence-structure

Ich habe folgenden Satzteil* geschrieben:

> Nur kann ich sagen, obwohl ich damit einverstanden bin, dass sie
> die Zeit als “langsamer” wahrnehmen, dass meines Erachtens das nur so
> ist, weil...

Mir hat mein Lehrer gesagt, dass der Satzbau nicht stimmte, dass es folgender sein sollte:

> Nur kann ich sagen, obwohl ich damit einverstanden bin, dass sie
> die Zeit als “langsamer” wahrnehmen, dass **das meines Erachtens** nur so
> ist, weil...

(ich habe die Änderungen **fett** gemacht).

Das heißt, "das" soll vor "meines Erachtens" gehen.

Wieso ist das so?  Kann mir jemand auf irgendeine Quelle deuten, die das erklären würde, d.h., diesen Aspekt des Satzbaus?

*(ich weiß, dass dieser alleinstehende Satzteil keinen Sinn ergibt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalerweise werden unbetonte Pronomen im Deutschen nach vorne gestellt, sie stehen oft im unmittelbaren Kontakt mit der Konjunktion. Ein wenig Beispieldiskussion findet sich hier: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objektpronomen#Subjekt-_und_Objektpronomen_im_Deutschen
(Ich sehe schon, dass es bei dir um ein Subjektpronomen geht, aber der Punkt ist so grundlegend, dass er sogar bei Objektpronomen den Ausschlag gibt).

Wortstellung ist im Deutschen aber immer verhandelbar. Das Adverbial "meines Erachtens" früher zu bringen, ist aber auffällig und führt zu Schwierigkeiten mit der Intonation des Satzes. Am besten wäre dann, es als Parenthese zu kennzeichnen, also dass es aus dem Satzverband herausgenommen wirkt: "...dass - jedenfalls *meines* Erachtens – das nur so ist, weil...".

Ich stimme außerdem der anderen Antwort zu, dass der Satzbau insgesamt stilistisch nicht optimal ist, und dass man einfacher und übersichtlicher konstruieren sollte...

Answer (score 1):

Both is correct, your teachers word order is more common or natural. Your choice put the emphasis slightly more on the 'das' in the bold highlighted part, yet that seems unnecessary.

Allow a remark regarding style: If you want to say something, simply say it. Don't say, you can say X. Don't complicate an already complicated  subject by using complicated, nested sentences and grammar. Use clear and to the point sentences. That helps to get your message across much more effectively. I'd rewrite your snippet to:

> Ich bin damit einverstanden, dass sie die Zeit langsamer wahrnehmen. Dennoch ist es meines Erachtens nur so, weil,...